# How can I parse for keyboard characters and display their graphical equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working on a software development QA project. I'd like to achieve key styling result for ex( <kbd>alt</kbd> ) like SO does it. Is there any plug-in that parses text and finds all keys, replaces with key images / or with css3?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: add this in your css..  kbd { /*styles goes here*/ }

Comment: So do you want a passage of "If I cannot enter a university, my life will end." be converted into "If I cannot <kbd>enter</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> university, my life will <kbd>end</kbd>."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin to do that, but you can easily create your own. The following plugin adds `kbd` tags just like in Alvin Wong's example. Note that this is quite a naive approach and you might get unwanted markup.

```
(function($){
    // List of keys
    var keys = ["ctrl", "alt", "esc", "del", "end", "num"];

    $.fn.keys = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            // Split text into words and remove line breaks
            var text = $(this).html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").split(" ");

            // Compare every word to every key
            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
                for (j in keys) {
                    if (text[i].toLowerCase() == keys[j]) {
                        text[i] = "<kbd>" + text[i] + "</kbd>";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            $(this).html(text.join(" "));
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can then add arbitrary style in your CSS stylesheet. See SO's stylesheet for some inspiration... ;)
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css

```
kbd {
    /* ... */
}
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/BUxpt/